# Материал по анимации переходов Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Захотел добавить в приложении анимацию открытия и закрытия `Activity` в приложении, основанном на `NavigationDrawer`: при нажатии на пункт, справа выезжает вторая (новая) `Activity`, закрывая собой первую. При нажатии кнопки "назад" — вторая (верхняя) `Activity` уезжает вправо, открывая собой первую (при этом первая изначально находится снизу и никак не двигается).

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу найти актуальную информацию. Официальный сайт молчит на эту тему, остальная информация находится на форумах, enSO и, за частую, не шибко работает на новых версиях Android'a.

---

Где можно найти актуальную информацию на тему анимирования переходов `Activity`?

Comment: Официальный сайт все же не молчит и даже [на русском "говорит"](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html?hl=ru) (раздел "переходы").

Comment: @pavlofff, разумеется я заходил на эту страницу. Там говорится о переходе между активностями только в контексте анимации преобразования, да и доступна она только с API 21. Грубо говоря, слишком мало материала именно на тему перехода между `Activity` средствами обычной анимации (о описании "best practices` и развернутых примеров уже и не говорю).

Answer (score 2):

`overridePendingTransition()` должно удовлетворить ваши требования

Comment: Только никто не рассказывает как правильно им пользоваться. Ничего, что в полной мере рассказывает о методе и о том, как *правильно* его использовать.

Comment: [...](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/overridependingtransition.php#overridependingtransition)

Comment: А тут никто не говорит о том, как добавить анимацию при закрытие, например. В вопросе я говорил о истник**ах**, которые полностью раскрывают эту тему, а бегло показывают функционал.

Comment: Тема настолько проста, что ссылка, которую я указал, с лихвой это всё покрывает. По крайней мере там написано гораздо больше, чем три строчки в оф. документации. ЗЫ: и про закрытие там тоже есть, читайте внимательно